# ajax request in angular js application not working in google chrome

Tags: angularjs, ajax, google-chrome

I'm working on an angular js application. I have loaded jquery and I'm using some jquery methods in this application. My problem is `$.ajax`. It's working in Firefox and IE, but has problem in google chrome! Google chrome always shows **Failed to load response data** error in my ajax request. Even if I send ajax request manually with `XMLHttpRequest()`(without jquery), I still see this error message in the chrome console. I don't know what's the problem and how can I solve this. Everything is perfect in firefox, even IE, but chrome has problem! Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/testUrl",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }
}).success(function(data) {
});
```

Note, I have used jquery ajax request in a non angular js application before and everything is right in google chrome, but when I switched to angular, I saw this strange problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery with angular is bad practice. Use the angular implementation for Ajax calls $http.

See this post
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2612-using-the-http-service-in-angularjs-to-make-ajax-requests.htm

And the official docs
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: I strongly disagree with your statement, not also to mention that it does not solve the OP's problem. The link that you provide is nowhere near the official documentation, which btw has got a whole page in the tutorial on how jquery can help. You just need to use jQuery in a different way than it is accustomed, and surely it should not be used in the OP's case.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can use build in service $http or $resource

Example:

```
  var data = ({
    dataType: "json", 
    headers: {
     Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}
    });

 $http.post('yoururl', data).success(function(data){
 console.log(data);
 });
```